# Can 2 relationships have a relationship between them (Database)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, associations, erd

Consider the scenario between a **Project**, **Task**, and a **User** (ER diagram attached included):

1. A project can have multiple tasks  and a task can be in multiple projects (thus the many-many relationship **ProjectTask**)
2. A project can have multiple users and a user can be in multiple projects (thus the many-many relationship **ProjectUser**)

[Check the above example's ER Diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIigb.png)

Now a ProjectTask can be assigned to multiple ProjectUsers and a ProjectUser can be assigned multiple ProjectTasks, basically a **TasksAssigned** relationship

How will I go about storing that information in a database? Can two relationships have a relationship? If yes, is there a better way to showcase this scenario? And if no, how do you show this relationship?

Comment: The relationship is between user and a task, not between relationships

Comment: The relationship between user and task won't hold information regarding which project it is from.

Comment: As it shouldn’t. The task has a relation to a project so it’s known which project it belongs to

Answer (score 0):

You can have a three-way relationship, in your case:

- `user`
- `project`
- `task`

You probably want to guarantee that the user and task have the same project.  That can be handled by declaring composite foreign keys to the `projectTasks` and `projectUsers` tables.  The structure guarantees that the user and task are in the same project (because it is explicitly mentioned in the row in this table).